# VBScript, Error 999999 Syntax Error Calculate Field in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, error-999999

I am using a field [all scores] as a parameter agricultural classification. I tried using field calculator (VB script) with many kinds script, but it never works and giving me notification 99999, syntax error.

I use this pre-logic.

```
Dim output
    If [all_score]>45 and [all_score]<80 then
        output="Dryland" 
    ElseIf[all_score]>79 and [all_score]<87 then
        output="Agricultural Wetland"
    ElseIf[all_score]>86 and [all_score]<137 then
        output="Plantation"
    Else
        output="Non- Agricultural"
    End If
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did the answer match what you were looking for? If so, please accept it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I would trying using parentheses:

```
    Dim output
        If ([all_score]>45 and [all_score]<80) then
            output="Dryland" 
        ElseIf ([all_score]>79 and [all_score]<87) then
            output="Agricultural Wetland"
        ElseIf ([all_score]>86 and [all_score]<137) then
            output="Plantation"
        Else
            output="Non- Agricultural"
        End If
```

[image]